# Ckeditor intigration with CKfinder

Tags: php, ckfinder

I integrate Ck finder with Ck Editor but when I click the browse button, a window came in front me with a message:

> "The file browser is disabled for security reasons. Please contact your system administrator and check the Ck Finder configuration file"

I don't know what to do

Comment: A good first step is to Google the error message: `The file browser is disabled for security reasons. Please contact your system administrator and check the Ck Finder configuration file` I think the first hit answers your question

Comment: yes i checked it already and also did same what he said but i am still facing the same problem

Comment: ok thanks alot Pekka i figure it out 

any one who facing this problem should use this code|

function CheckAuthentication()
{
   return true;
}

instead of that

function CheckAuthentication()
{
   return false;
}

Comment: @user1210460 Actually, if you read the comments above that code, it says something like "don't just return true"; that's supposed to be used in conjunction with an ACL

Answer (score 0):

1. Download CKEditor and CKFinder.
2. Put extracted code of both in one folder inside xampp as below.
3. Create index file (index.html) which will be containing the editor as below code.

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <h1>CKEditor CKFinder Integration using PHP</h1>
       <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
       filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
       filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
       filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
       filebrowserUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
       filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
       filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'
   });
   CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '../' );
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

so your folder structure will be something like this:

```
htdocs
|_integrated
    |_ckeditor
    |   |_config.js
    |   |_...
    |_ckfinder
    |   |_config.php
    |   |_...
    |_uploads
    |_index.html
```

1. Now open file config.php inside ckfinder & make following changes:

   ```
   function CheckAuthentication() {
       // WARNING : DO NOT simply return "true". By doing so, you are allowing
       // "anyone" to upload and list the files in your server. You must implement
       // some kind of session validation here. Even something very simple as...
       // return isset($_SESSION['IsAuthorized']) && $_SESSION['IsAuthorized'];
       return true; // not good option though; go for sessions
   }
   $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/integrated/uploads/';
   $enabled = true;
   $config['SecureImageUploads'] = false;
   $config['ChmodFolders'] = 0777 ;
   ```
2. Now open url `http://localhost/integrated/` and try uploading image.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers are not welcome here.

Comment: Did you bother to read the comment stating "don't just return true in the CheckAuthentication function?" You have now provided free hosting for everyone on your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here:

    function CheckAuthentication()
    {

        return false;
    }
```

By default `CheckAuthentication()` it is disabled for security reason, because it would allow anyone to upload files to your server.

For testing purposes you can return `true` but the point is that you implement some logic to only authorize autenticated user.

```
    function CheckAuthentication()
    {
        //put some logic here

        return isset($_SESSION['IsAuthorized']) && $_SESSION['IsAuthorized'];
    }
```